# How to erase unsued space so that dumping userdata partition creates a sparse file of small size?

Tags: rooting, backup, file-system, shell, partitions

When I create a `gzip` image of `userdata` partition (`/dev/block/mmcblk0p29`) it creates huge 6.8GB image, previously it was 350MB.

Is it possible through command-line to erase or wipe or delete space on `userdata` partition? I want to keep small compact compressed `gzip` or shadow images of clean unrooted and rooted partition on various dates and times.

I tried the following commands but nothing worked for me:

1. `fastboot erase userdata`
2. `rm -r /data/*.*`
3. `rm -r /sdcard/*.*`

Still image is 6.8GB.

4. `dd if=/dev/zero if=/dev/block/platform/7824900.sdhci/by-name/userdata bs=8192`
5. `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/block/platform/7824900.sdhci/by-name/userdata bs=8192`

`/dev/zero` and `/dev/urandom` not found in device.

6. `newfs`
7. iShredder 3 app
8. Secure Eraser app
9. Andro Shredder or Disk Sanitizer

But how will I format in unrooted while working in the Android userdata partition?

10. Any `adb shell` command to clear, format or zero fill

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a troubleshooting forum. Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102824/discussion-on-question-by-androidquery-safely-format-zero-fill-unsued-space-in). **To the asker**: please [edit] the question according to the comment feedback to focus on a single, answerable issue.

Comment: @IrfanLatif kindly post the **comments in chat** as **answer** so i can vote and accept it  as this question you edited and explained and gave me answers for trim and zero fill and e2image that all worked a greatful thanks to you for all your  efforts and precious advice

Answer (score 1):

I guess your real purpose of this question is not what the headline suggests - secure erase your data - but instead you want to have a full backup of userdata including `/data/media` (downvote if I am wrong).

You have some options, most require additional binaries which you can copy to `/cache` partition or permanently integrate into your twrp `/sbin`:

- [e2image](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=4349826312261690359) (thx @IrfanLatif)
- make twrp backup of /data to internal storage and just `adb pull -a /sdcard` afterwards, which you can zip without worry about file permissions
- just create tar.gz instead of img.gz with gnu [tar](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2649724&goto=newpost) (with `--selinux --xattrs -p` flags)
- create empty disk image and copy all (`mke2fs` + `busybox cp -ac`) then compress img with `gz` (requires much disk space and underlying non-fat32 file system type)
- permanent [tweak](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3941108) for twrp

(I will improve this answer when I have time)

Comment: yes purpose is image backup userdata partition problem  its creating image including empty space deleted data  i want clear it first  ... e2image is  not found in system/bin kindly tell way to install in android.....twrp backup tried  but  dont copy media and all other files.........tar.gz with --selinux flag works in android 7 and i am using  android lolipop 5.1.1 ......empty disk image and copy all (mke2fs + busybox cp -acv) then compress img with gz takes too much time .. and its recompressing is a lengthy procedure..... tweaking twrp i havent tried yet will try to see it...

Comment: i am pretty sure the gnu tar binary i have compiled is backwards compatible - if not, download for your platform [open_gapps.zip](https://opengapps.org)

Comment: i founded a command for  trimming the  device partition  directly  after unmounting it   is it  a safe  a command  e2fsck -E discard /dev/block/mmcblk0p29 (userdata partition block)